# Forms opened in DLL shows in task manager, how to hide?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe2

I have a number of forms that are launched, via COM, in a XE2 DLL.  The caller is a VC 6 application.

Every form that opens up shows up as an application in TaskManager, I don't want that, these windows are just dialog boxes, not applications.

Is there a setting I can use to not have these windows show?

I am using C++ Builder XE2, but a Delphi solution would probably work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TaskManager shows top-level unowned windows.  Your DLL windows do not have any owner windows specified.  That is why they appear.

Answer (score 1):

Set TForm.BorderStyle to bsToolWindow or bsSizeToolWin.
That would cause [WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61fe4bte.aspx) included in Win32 window styles.

Or you can manually set those if you override [CreateParams](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CreateParams) method.

I also think [WS_POPUPWINDOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) is to be set in CreateParams, it's description suggests it.

Last but not least, i'd try to pass [main window handle](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=mfc+hwnd&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) from C++ application, then assign it as [parent hwnd](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.ParentWindow) to your dialog windows, if those windows are not modal.